# What is the meaning of Mass?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In Biography English movie *Marie Antoinette (2006)*, Scene where French queens having dinner with American's generals.
At Dinner table, Ducchess De Polignac asked everybody to lick a finger and rub it
on a glass. So all did and it produced beautiful sound. 
One woman, who is sitting beside her, asked this question to her
and everybody laughed.

> French Queen#1: It's very spiritual, really, isn't it?
>
> French Queen#2: When was the last time you went to **Mass**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, "Mass" is referring to a religious Mass:

> Mass is the central act of worship in the life of a Catholic. Going to Mass is about spending time with God, but also receiving his graces (inner strength to live the Christian life). The name ‘Mass’ comes the final blessing said by the priest in Latin ‘Ite missa es’ meaning “to send out” as Jesus Christ sent his disciples out to the world to take his teaching to them.

[Source](http://www.thepapalvisit.org.uk/The-Catholic-Faith/FAQ-on-Faith/1-10/What-is-a-Catholic-Mass)